# Searching for Latest data in a fast growing SQL Server Database table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am building an IOT application where sensor data is logged into a SQL Server database into a table called `SENSOR_DATA`.

The columns and datatype of the `SENSOR_DATA` table are specified below

```
ID             BIGINT
SENSOR_ID      BIGINT
READINGS_DATE  DATETIME
READING        DOUBLE
```

At least each sensor will produce about 600 readings a day to be logged into the database.

A total of about 1000 sensors is to be accommodated.

This implies that each day, there will be about 1000 x 600 = "600,000" `INSERTS`.

The most frequently used query will be to obtain the latest readings (based on `DATETIME` column) of all sensors.

I have currently implemented this using a correlated query. The way the query is composed, i have a strong feeling it is going to be processor and memory hungry.

I have come up with a work around which i explain below:

- Create a second table called `LATEST_SENSOR_DATA`.
- When inserting data into the `SENSOR_DATA` table, update the corresponding value in the `LATEST_SENSOR_DATA` table.

Using this technique, I only have to query the much smaller `LATEST_SENSOR_DATA` table using only the required `ID` of the sensor.

How does this solution sound and are there any other workarounds?

UPDATE ON 11/02/2019

Hello guys. Thanks for your feedback. Been very helpful in pointing me in the right direction. First I will like to state that I am inexperienced setting up a database for production.

I will like to give a bit more information on the database design.

1. As was rightly suggested by Gordon Linoff, there is sensor master table that contains some meta information about the sensor. This means the “sensor_id” column in the sensor_data table is a foreign key column.
2. Aside from frequently retrieving latest sensor data, users will also moderately query for a particular sensor’s  data for a particular day / week / month.
3. Data in the sensor_data table will never be updated or deleted by the user. (Except for archiving purposes, where data will be deleted in blocks).
4. It is envisioned to keep data for past three months.
   Now, I have done some reading into indexes and how they can speed up data retrieval, as well as the cost involved in maintaining them.

A particular type of INDEX that caught my attention was “filttered indexes”. With these I can create a filtered index on the (readings_date, sensor_is) columns for every month.
The benefits of this is that, I will have “small” manageable indexes that will be better to maintain than one big index for the whole table (full table index).
With this solution, I believe I may have to stick to my original plan of maintaining a latest_sensor_data table.

Now my question is which of the two scenarios is better

1. Create only filtered indexes. Use latest_sensor_data table for latest data.
2. Create one big full table index. Query latest data using full table index.

Gordon Linoff was also right in guessing what query I was using to retrieve latest data (first query in his answer). It took me a while to understand his second query, but I now understand why such a query is far better than the query I was using. Thanks.

PS: it took me a while to decipher his syntax for table aliases. I learnt that the “AS” keyword was required, but in actual fact optional.

Comment: How many days are you wanting to query without going to the "all" table? And how frequently are you wanting to query this information? Also, can you provide the actual table definition including clustering and indexes?

Comment: Think about this: you will slow the insert operation (because of the new update) so the SELECT will be faster. How many inserts are you going to have per day vs how many selects?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a sensible way to speed up access to the latest values.

Comment: ..And how many days are you storing the readings?

Comment: Actually, other than your 'strong feeling', do you have any requirement to speed up either INSERT or SELECT? Beware of premature optimisation!

Comment: How is your query execution plan looking?  Does it avoid table scan and index scan?  Has your table got suitable indexes?

Comment: Generally speaking, it doesn't make sense to duplicate data how you are describing. With the proper index, specifically a NCI on SENSOR_ID, READINGS_DATE DESC, this would be pretty fast. You could also materialize a view. Both of these are arguably better than duplicating the data in a persisted table. Don't optimize by creating another insert process before starting with your query plan and indexes, maxdop, paralell thresholds, stats updates, etc. You siad you have a feeling it will eat up memory. So what? If there is memory to spare it's not an issue! Show us the execution plan :)

Comment: What are your proposed indexes specifically?  What are you going to filter by?  I can't see why not to have the whole table indexed.  You've not explained what you want to exclude

Comment: @Cato The indexes will be filtered using readings_date column. So the filtering condition will be like "BETWEEN 2019-01-01 AND 2019-02-01". I am having reservations about the cost involved in maintaining a whole table index because my solution involves a significant amount of inserts

Comment: to be honest, I gave you the SQL to generate a large test data, so you should be able to test your queries with different indexes - but perhaps with a partial index, it won't cover all values available and the query will switch to a painful Table Scan - if you index only recent rows, then new recent rows will get added to that index.  Once the date in the index is no longer 'recent' then they will not get added.  So to keep the index useful (if it is useful) you might need to keep modifying it.

Answer (score 2):

800,000 inserts per day is significant.  That is, on average, 10 inserts per second.

A query such as:

```
select sd.*
from sensor_data sd
where sd.readings_date = (select max(sd2.readings_date)
                          from sensor_data sd2
                          where sd2.sensor_id = sd.sensor_id
                         );
```

is reasonable.  But, probably involves a full scan of the entire table, even with an index on `sensor_data(sensor_id, readings_date)`.

This can be ameliorated by writing the query as:

```
select sd.*
from sensors s cross apply  -- I assume you have such a table
     (select top (1) sd.*
      from sensor_data sd
      where sd.sensor_id = s.sensor_id
      order by sd.readings_date desc
     ) sd;
```

This should use the index to get the appropriate row for each sensor.

You can make this faster by adding `sensor_date` to a clustered index, so all the latest rows occur together.  This will probably be true in practice, so this might not be necessary.  This is not a consideration for fetching data about one sensor.

By comparison, adding a new table with values from a trigger will help.  But you need to balance slowing down 800,000 inserts per day for whatever queries you are going to be running.

Depending on your recency needs, you might find it sufficient to copy the data to another database (even on another server) using a periodic SQL Server Agent job.  Then use that other database to summarize the data in a "data mart".  This balances the "slowing down of inserts using a trigger" with the "fast response needs" of an application.

For any of this, you need to test and test to see what works best in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Good news I reckon, you don't need a duplicate data table

first I made large test data

```
truncate table sensor_data;
WITH NOS AS (SELECT row_number() OVER (order by a.name) N FROM sys.all_objects  a,sys.all_objects b)
    insert into sensor_data 
    SELECT  
         row_number() over (order by qsens.n) ID,
         qsens.n Sensor_ID,
        dateadd(second,
                qread.n,
                dateadd(day,qd.n,CAST('20150101' as datetime))
                ) readings_date
                , 456.255 + log(qd.n + qsens.n+qread.n) as reading 
        from nos as qsens, nos as qd , nos as qread
        where qsens.n<=100 and qd.n<1300 and qread.n <=600;


select distinct S1.Sensor_ID  into SENSORS from sensor_data S1;
```

(and I have made the Sensors Table suggested by Gordon Linoff)

then I added an index

```
CREATE nonCLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20190204-151527] ON [dbo].[SENSOR_DATA]
(
    [Sensor_ID] ASC,
    [Readings_Date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

then the following query gives the latest for each sensor very efficiently.

```
select distinct S1.Sensor_ID,SQ.Reading,sq.Readings_Date,sq.ID  from SENSORS S1 
       outer apply (SELECT TOP 1 * from sensor_data S2 
                                    WHERE s2.Sensor_ID = s1.Sensor_ID
                                    ORDER BY S2.Readings_Date DESC) SQ;
```

Without the 'sensors' table and the index, it runs very badly.

note:  I experimented with making an indexed view of unique sensor IDs, that also works very well with the query (after tackling some issues setting up the indexed view).  However their suitability for use on intensely updated tables was questioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have mentioned is correct and gives the fatest query response time instead of query the main table which keeps all the sensor reads it better to keep latest read entry either in the separate table or you can keep the latest read columns with your sensor master table which you may have.

Comment: While I generally agree with smaller datasets produce data faster, the insert overhead and deleting non-latest records has overhead as well.

Comment: It adds complexity to the solution.